# How to automatically refresh data with Redux Toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to achieve automated refetching without using RTK Query.
I.e. im writing my API calls using createAsyncThunk & Axios.

On create(post) or update(patch) request being successful, I would rather just "refetch" data, rather than push my changes into the original data set.

This is how it would be done with RTK Query:https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/automated-refetching
By invalidating the data.

A simple solution would be if I could call my "fetchClients" thunk..

Any ideas?

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, current } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/";
import axios from "axios";
import { getAxiosHeaders } from "../Api/apiHelper";


const initialState = {
  clients: [],
  client: null,
  status: "idle", //'idle' | 'loading' | 'succeeded' | 'failed'
  error: null,
  isModalOpen: false,
};

export const fetchClients = createAsyncThunk("clients/fetchClients", async () => {
  alert("hello fetch clients");
  const response = await axios.get(CLIENTS_URL, { headers });
  return response.data.clients;
});


export const addNewClient = createAsyncThunk("clients/addNewClient", async (body) => {
  const response = await axios.post(CLIENTS_URL, body, { headers });
  return response.data;
});

export const clientsSlice = createSlice({
  name: "clients",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    toggleModal: (state, action) => {
      state.isModalOpen = !action.payload;
    },

    },
  },

  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchClients.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "loading";
      })
      .addCase(fetchClients.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "success";
        state.clients = action.payload;
      
      })

      .addCase(fetchClients.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = "failed";
        state.error = action.error.message;
      })

      .addCase(addNewClient.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        console.log(state.clients);
        // REFETCH DATA i.e. fetchClients()
        // state.clients.push(action.payload);
      })

  },
});


export const { clientAdded, toggleModal, setClient } = clientsSlice.actions;
export default clientsSlice.reducer;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason why you're trying to avoid using RTK Query? It _is_ possible to write this yourself if you really need to (it's just code!), but much of the point of RTKQ is that you _shouldn't_ have to write any of this data fetching code yourself.

Comment: Agree, I've since had a more in depth look at RTK Query.  Initially I thought it would be difficult to customize. My end goal is to couple RTK and Firebase and I figured while going through the workflows that the above approach would be better suited.